# xamarin google drive API

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.mac

i am trying to setup my first google drive application.
i have written C# code compiled on VS2015 and works like charm. But when i used the same code to run it on xamarin. it does not allow me and keeps saying missing namespace or reference at this statement

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential (new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer (serviceaccount) {
                Scopes = scopes
            }.FromCertificate (certificate));
```

i have installed the latest NuGet Package Google.APis.Drive.V2 Ver. 1.9.2.193
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realised the following
installing via NuGet didn't reference the this assembly: Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll

I do not know why ... but now it works.